# How to resize pasted image to fit the original image perfectly

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

This is the original image:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and these are the images that I need to paste on it:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

When I paste it the resultant image is:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and this is the code:

```
def applyWireAugmentation(img, wire_img,wdir, odir, theata,dst_path, counter, index):

    src_im = Image.open(wdir+wire_img).convert("LA")
    dst_im = Image.open(odir+img)
    w,h = dst_im.size
    ww,wh = src_im.size
    angle = theata
    size = w, h

    x = random.randint(0,w/2)
    y = 0
    im = src_im.convert('RGBA')
    rot = im.rotate( angle, expand=1 ).resize(size)
    dst_im.paste( rot, (x, y), rot )
    dst_im.save(dst_path+"/"+img.replace(".png","")+"-"+index+"-"+str(counter)+".png")
```

I need to stretch the pasted image such that its ends meet the original image. How do I do that in a generic way?

Edit: Expected output:

Consider black line to be the wire. Wire should be stretched to meet ends of image itself

Comment: Can you please provide an image of the expected output, maybe using GIMP or similar tools? From your description, it's not clear, where the wire should start and end.

Comment: How are the "ends" of the pasted determined. How should they be position relative to original image, especially of it's bee rotated some arbitrary amount. You question can't be answered without know these things.

Comment: @martineau it can be positioned anywhere on the image. x is chosen randomly.

Comment: First of all, you'd need to crop the wire properly from the PNG, maybe by using the alpha channel. Then, a simple resize to the "background" image shape should be fine. Nevertheless, for that, I would switch to NumPy arrays and do all further operations using NumPy/OpenCV. Are you bound to Pillow/PIL?

Comment: @HansHirse no Im not but it seems kinda easire

Comment: Can you explain the cropping a bit more.

Comment: cropped it using src_im = src_im.crop((0, 0, ww-3, wh-3)) . Not helping

Comment: The program would have to determine the position in order to make the "ends" to meet, although I still don't know what those are or how to determine that is. Image have 4 sides, top, bottom, left and right. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @martineau I want to merge the wire with the original image. It would look as if wire is part of the image.

Comment: You would need to enlarge the image so it was bigger than the target image and then crop it to fit. How much bigger would depend on how thick the wire was. The problem is complicated by the fact that you are allow the image to also be rotated, and that would also have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Since I also don't understand, what you want to achieve with that random placement and rotating, I focussed on the cropping and stretching of the wire. As stated before, I prefer NumPy/OpenCV for such operation. (Conversion from and to Pillow/PIL is no problem.)

That'd be my suggestion:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web reading images

# Web read images via scikit-image; convert to OpenCV's BGR color ordering
bg = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGP1I.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
wire = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1GCd.png'), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)

# Crop wire in alpha channel
rect = cv2.boundingRect(wire[:, :, 3])
wire = wire[rect[1]:(rect[1] + rect[3]), rect[0]:(rect[0] + rect[2])]

# Resize cropped wire to background image shape
wire = cv2.resize(wire, (bg.shape[1], bg.shape[0]))

# Paste wire on background image
bg[wire[:, :, 3] > 0, :] = wire[wire[:, :, 3] > 0, :3]

# Output
cv2.imshow('bg', bg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And that'd be the output:

[image: Output]

The output doesn't look nice, but that's mostly due to the alpha channel of the wire. One would need improvements on that issue.

If that's not the desired output, please let me know.

However – hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: You left the arbitrary rotation of the wire image out…

Comment: This is exactly what was required. Is there any way to make this wire thinner?

Comment: And please explain your logic

Comment: @martineau Yes - as I also stated myself in my answer. Since I used a significantly different approach than in the question (NumPy/OpenCV vs. Pillow/PIL), there was no intent from my side to address the "full issue" here.

Comment: What if I want to paste it at an arbitrary location like in given question?